# How can I sort an object in symfony?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, oop, usort

This is "fields"

```
{#751 ▼
  +"id": array:9 [▼
    "fieldName" => "id"
    "type" => "integer"
    "scale" => 0
    "length" => null
    "unique" => true
    "nullable" => false
    "precision" => 0
    "id" => true
    "columnName" => "id"
  ]
  +"username": array:8 [▼
    "fieldName" => "username"
    "type" => "string"
    "scale" => 0
    "length" => 25
    "unique" => true
    "nullable" => false
    "precision" => 0
    "columnName" => "username"
  ]
  +"unique_id": array:8 [▼
    "fieldName" => "unique_id"
    "type" => "string"
    "scale" => 0
    "length" => 10
    "unique" => true
    "nullable" => false
    "precision" => 0
    "columnName" => "unique_id"
  ]
  +"password": array:8 [▼
    "fieldName" => "password"
    "type" => "string"
    "scale" => 0
    "length" => 64
    "unique" => false
    "nullable" => false
    "precision" => 0
    "columnName" => "password"
  ]
  +"email": array:8 [▼
    "fieldName" => "email"
    "type" => "string"
    "scale" => 0
    "length" => 191
    "unique" => true
    "nullable" => false
    "precision" => 0
    "columnName" => "email"
  ]
  +"isActive": array:8 [▼
    "fieldName" => "isActive"
    "type" => "boolean"
    "scale" => 0
    "length" => null
    "unique" => false
    "nullable" => false
    "precision" => 0
    "columnName" => "is_active"
  ]
}
```

I would like that username is always at the beginning and password is always at the end.

Here is my approach:

```
  usort($fields, function ($a, $b) {  if ($a['fieldName'] == 'username' || $b['fieldName'] == 'password') return -1;
        elseif ($a['fieldName'] == 'password' || $b['fieldName'] == 'username') return 1;
        else return 0;
      });
```

But I get an error message:

> Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: @Thefourthbird This gives the error `Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference`

Comment: Then first cast it to an array `$fields = (array)$fields;
usort($fields`

Comment: Or you can use `$fields = json_decode(json_encode($fields), true);` in order to cast to array in different way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter of [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) should be an array and `$fields` is an object. One option could be to cast it to an array like:

```
$fields = (array)$fields;
```

And then pass it to usort:

```
usort($fields, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a['fieldName'] == 'username' || $b['fieldName'] == 'password') return -1;
    elseif ($a['fieldName'] == 'password' || $b['fieldName'] == 'username') return 1;
    else return 0;
});
```